# CICD using VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

With CICD done, On every commit VSTS creates the build and deploys it to the target environment successfully.

I want to understand how the build is done, is it incremental OR full build every time I commit the change in the .net project.

If anytime I want to rollback, to the previous working build does VSTS does it or I need to configure or follow some procedures to do it hassle free ?

Comment: Start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/what-is-release-management and if you have any specific questions, create a post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Hosted agent**, it is full build every time. (Need to download source, build whole projects)

If you are using **private build agent** and do not clear anything (e.g. In Get sources, **clean** is false; Visual Studio Build task, **clean** option unchecked), part of build will be up to date if source not be changed. (can just download the updated files and skip some build targets if build results are up to date)

The VSTS can’t rollback the build, you can roll back changes, then rebuild and redeploy. There is a blog about rollback: [Implement Rollback with Release Management](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/03/28/implement-rollback-with-release-management-for-tfs-2015/).